# How to compare two protobuffer files in c#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net 2.3.2 in my .net application to generate buffer file.

```
public class EmailData
{
    public string FirstName{ set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public Location Location { set; get; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string LocaitionName{ set; get; }
    public string ZipCode{ set; get; }   

}
```

I want to know if there is any api to compare 2 buffer files generated using the EmailData class

Comment: I don't think that'll be possible without deserializing them back to objects...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The binary data *may* be identical (and often will be), but it is not a hard guarantee - the same semantic data can be represented in different byte data. So: you'll need to deserialize and handle this separately.